# passing va_args to a custom format function

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I'd like to use a va_args list in a custom formatter function.

I first tried to get vsnprintf() to work to verifiy that my argument pointer list itself is passed correctly => this worked

But when i tried to pass my argument pointer list to another function the pointer does not point to the right element on the stack

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>


int wrapper_snprintf(char *s, size_t n, const char *format, ...)
{
  va_list arg;
  //Copy Formated string to buffer => adds a terminating null character to the string
  va_start(arg, format);
  int res = vsnprintf(s, n, format, arg);
  va_end(arg);

  return res;
}

void Va_Args_Test_C(char *fmt, ...)
{

  char test[30] = { 0 };
  char test2[30] = { 0 };
  {
    //vsnprintf
    va_list arg;

    va_start(arg, fmt);
    vsnprintf(test2, 30, fmt, arg);
    va_end(arg);

  }

  {
    //custom format function
      va_list arg;

      va_start(arg, fmt);
      wrapper_snprintf(test2, 30, fmt, arg);
      va_end(arg);

    }


}
```

the first run worked. The correct argument is copied to string test[].

the second run did not work. test2[] contains the original string + some random number (which looks like a crappy pointer to me). So could you help me? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case you call `vsnprintf(test2, 30, fmt, arg);`. 
This function is defined as

```
int vsnprintf(char *str, size_t size, const char *format, va_list ap);
```

In the second case you call `wrapper_snprintf(test2, 30, fmt, arg);`, but your is defined differently as

```
int wrapper_snprintf(char *s, size_t n, const char *format, ...)
```

This is as if you would call `snprintf` instead of `vsnprintf`.

If you want a replacement for `vsnprintf` you have to define your function with an argument of type `va_list` instead of `...`

```
int wrapper_snprintf(char *s, size_t n, const char *format, va_list ap)
{
  //Copy Formated string to buffer => adds a terminating null character to the string

  int res = vsnprintf(s, n, format, ap);

  return res;
}
```